# display category title in django

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, django-templates

I am trying to display the title for the category if it has a title that I want to display, but what happens is that it displays all the titles for the categories

#models

```
class category(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    head_titel = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    titel = models.TextField(max_length=1000)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
    def get_absolute_url (self):
        return reverse('store')  

class Product(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=7,decimal_places=2)
    category = models.CharField(choices=choice_list,max_length=255)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

    @property
    def imageURL(self):
        try:
            url = self.image.url
        except:
            url = ''
        return url
```

#view

```
def CategoryView(request,cats):
    data= cartData(request)
    cartItems = data['cartItems']
    cat_menu = category.objects.all()
    Category_Post = Product.objects.filter(category__iexact=cats.replace('-' ,' '))
    cate = Product.objects.all()
    return render (request,'store/catogrise.html',{'cats':cats.title().replace('-',' ') ,
     'Category_Post':Category_Post,'cat_menu':cat_menu,'cat_menu':cat_menu,'cartItems':cartItems,'cate':cate})
```

#template

```
{% for cate in cat_menu %}
            <div class="cartEmpty">
                    <h4>{{cate.head_titel}}</h4>
                    <div class="CartEmpaty">
                        <small class="a-size-Cart">
                        <p>{{cate.titel}}</p></small>
                    </div>
                </div>
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: The models have no relationship

Answer (score 0):

It displays all titles because you don't filter cat_menu in the view:

```
cat_menu = category.objects.all()
```

you should add filter there, for example:

```
cat_menu = category.objects.filter(name__contains='some_string')
```

Another problem is that your context has the same field twice:

```
'cat_menu':cat_menu,'cat_menu':cat_menu
```